# Sharpening scissors with microserrations

Tags: sharpening

I own Sabatier Proffessional scissors (like [those](https://www.hartsofstur.com/sabatier-professional-soft-grip-22cm-8-5-kitchen-scissor-sabprsc02.html)). One of the blades has microserrations along the edge (see the picture below). How should I sharpen them? I presume that I'd destroy the serrations if I just tried sharpening it the same way as I do with non serrated edge?

As far as the tools go, I own Work Sharp Knife and Tool Sharpener (which I like very much) and Spyderco Sharpmaker (which I was not able to use to its full potential, hence replaced that with WSKT).

[image: Serrated edge]

Comment: You can't sharpen them.  I recommend contacting Sabatier.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I would say this is an answer.

Comment: I expect that it's the only one they'll get.  Here goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that you can't sharpen microserrated blades effectively, and generally end up damaging them.

I recommend [contacting Sabatier](https://www.sabatier-shop.com/contact) instead, or talking to a professional knife sharpener.